# Azure load balancer session affinity not sticking. Why?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

My client makes two http requests to my cloud service which has two replicas. 
According to documentation (1) and since connection is kept alive, I'd expect the two requests to go to the same replica.

However, I see each request goes to a different replica. For performance reasons, this is undesirable.

What is causing the distribution?

How do I debug load balancer?

(1) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-distribution-mode/

Comment: I assume you've enabled `sourceIP` mode?

Comment: No. It is using the default which should be the 5-item tuple.

Comment: Well, okay, then requests will only go to the same instance if they use the same underlying TCP connection.

Answer (score 1):

The default distribution will be 5-tuple (SourceIP, Destination IP, source Port, Destination Port, Protocol). It means that each new connection initiated by a client may land to a different server

If you use sourceIP, then the stickiness will be based on the client IP address

If you need application based stickiness (such as cookie based affinity, then you may look at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/application-gateway/

Yves